# 404 error on Stack Exchange API website

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

The Add flag page on the API site https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment-flag doesn't work correctly and when inspected, I saw a **404 error** for a resource at `https://api.stackexchange.com/mini-profiler-resources/results` from a JavaScript file `includes.js?v=Aui3dzK2894/R4HUIPFKQX2NEsCIEjFZ5JHtKI8sQno=:1060` So, the resource request is made internally.

[image]

**But when visiting the link, the resource exists:**

[image]

The POST request returns 404 anyway.

**The screenshot of request**

[image]

Comment: @ArtOfCode no there are many differences. I believe that's why rene removed his comment

Comment: @ArtOfCode it is not a dupe. The same error is in other question, this is different.